# How do I reconnect my outlet?

Tags: receptacle

I took apart an outlet for doing some drywall work. I have an outlet that has two black, two white and I believe four grounds. This is where I am confused. One ground should go to receptacle. Should it not? Or do I take the green screw in back of the box and run it into the wire nut with other two ground wires?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the innards of the box?

Answer (score 2):

Four ground wires.

- One to the upstream supply  (along with a black and white)
- One to the downstream load (along with a black and white)
- One to the steel box
- One to the receptacle

Works for me.

Comment: And all four of those should be joined together with a green wire nut.

Comment: Either a wire nut, or a crimp sleeve designed for this purpose would work. The sleeve is less likely to come apart than the nut, and takes up slightly less space. Useful when space is at a premium.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a green wire nut. Here at SE we don't discriminate by color, gender or national origin!